# WPF ScrollBar styles

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, scrollbar

Is it possible to create scrollbars like in this picture?
[image]

This picture was taken from this link: http://codesdirectory.blogspot.be/2013/01/wpf-scrollviewer-control-style.html.
I tried the example in the post but the result looked like this:[image]

The post is 3 years old so this may be normal.

Is it possible to create scrollbars like the first picture? I have been looking for hours to find a template and this is the closest I could get.
I am converting a windows form app to a WPF and the main reason for that was the scrollbars!
This is the xaml from the above pictures:

```
<Window x:Class="iBlock.MainWindow"

        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        Title="WPF ScrollViewer" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ScrollBar.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <ScrollViewer Background="#F7F7F7"

                      BorderBrush="#C7C7C7"

                      Height="300"

                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

                      Margin="10"

                      Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=styleScrollViewer}"

                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

                      Width="400">

            <StackPanel Background="Red" Height="400" Width="500"></StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Got it working with a little help from some research:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardBackgroundBrush" Color="Black" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverBorderBrush" Color="#DDD" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="Gray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedForegroundBrush" Color="White" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" Color="#FF686868" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListBoxBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0.001">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.6" />
                <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="1.2"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="StandardBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Name="Border" Margin="1" CornerRadius="2" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Background="Black" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0"  Width="8" Margin="8,0,-2,0"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="Transparent" />
    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Height="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand" Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
    <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" IsDirectionReversed="true">
        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.Thumb>
            <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Margin="1,0,1,0" Background="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBorderBrush}" />
        </Track.Thumb>
        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Height="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="#F0F0F0"/>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0"  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z" />
            <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Margin="0,1,0,1" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="FavsScrollViewer" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: I am unable to understand how you have hidden RepeatButtons? As changing Visibility for ScrollBarLineButton doesnt work

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for @John P. and @crackanddie

After I use the code of them and fixed a square at the right bottom.
Then the completed code is below.

You can create a new resource dictionary file name's "Scrollbar.xaml"
Then put these code

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardBorderBrush"
                 Color="#888" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardBackgroundBrush"
                 Color="Black" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverBorderBrush"
                 Color="#DDD" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush"
                 Color="Gray" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedForegroundBrush"
                 Color="White" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush"
                 Color="#888" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush"
                 Color="#444" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush"
                 Color="#888" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush"
                 Color="#888" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush"
                 Color="#C8C8C8" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush"
                 Color="#888" />

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility"
            Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        Margin="1"
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                          Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility"
            Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Background="Black" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb"
       TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border CornerRadius="4"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Width="8"
                        Margin="8,0,-2,0" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbHor"
       TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border CornerRadius="4"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Height="8"
                        Margin="0,0,-2,0" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.RowSpan="3"
                CornerRadius="2"
                Background="Transparent" />
        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0"
                      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                      Height="18"
                      Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"
                      Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
        <Track Name="PART_Track"
               Grid.Row="1"
               IsDirectionReversed="true">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                              Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
                       Margin="1,0,1,0"
                       Background="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBrush}"
                       BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBorderBrush}" />
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                              Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="3"
                      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                      Height="18"
                      Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand"
                      Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                CornerRadius="3"
                Background="Transparent" />
        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0"
                      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                      Width="18"
                      Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand"
                      Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z" />
        <Track Name="PART_Track"
               Grid.Column="1"
               IsDirectionReversed="False">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                              Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbHor}"
                       Margin="0,1,0,1"
                       Background="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBrush}"
                       BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBorderBrush}" />
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                              Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="3"
                      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                      Width="18"
                      Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand"
                      Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                 Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                 Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="FavsScrollViewer"
       TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" />
                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in App.xaml file

put this code

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

           <!-- This line change Views/Styles to your path to Scrollbar.xaml -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Views/Styles/Scrollbar.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then using it in your view .xaml file with

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
     <!-- Your code here -->
     <Grid />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 5):

I removed obsolete elements from the code of the last answer (ice thailand) and adjusted the margins a bit. This is the resource I use now:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="EslScrollbarThumb" Color="#8b8b8b" />

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Width="6" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbHor" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Height="6" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Track
            Name="PART_Track"
            IsDirectionReversed="true">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb
                    Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
                    Margin="2,0,2,0"
                    Background="{DynamicResource EslScrollbarThumb}" />
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Track
            Name="PART_Track"
            IsDirectionReversed="False">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb
                    Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbHor}"
                    Margin="0,2,0,2"
                    Background="{DynamicResource EslScrollbarThumb}" />
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="FavsScrollViewer" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" />
                        <ScrollBar
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                        <ScrollBar
                            Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ScrollBar
                            x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                        <ScrollBar
                            x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 4):

ok, there was some problems with Danny's code. When I tried to activate Horizontal scrollbar it was very small

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource FavsScrollViewer}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  Margin="6,0,0,0">
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

[old scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHD2D.jpg)
so i found the solution. You have to create a new style like mine:

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbHor" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="1" Background="#c8c8c8" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0"  Height="8" Margin="0,0,-2,0"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And then change the thumb style in the horizontal scrollbar template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="0" Background="#006464"/>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0"  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z" />
            <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbHor}" Margin="0,1,0,1" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

So now it looks nice
[image: now scroll bar]