# UWP ScrollViewer scrolling work with mouse wheel but not with touch

Tags: c#, uwp

I needed to define 2 ScrollBars for one ScrollViewer [UWP ScrollBar styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156452/uwp-scrollbar-styles). Styles work but there was a problem, I lost the ability to scroll with touch. After I touch the Thumb, it is no longer attached to the mouse wheel and can only be moved with a mouse click.

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Border x:Name="Root" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        >
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                          Grid.RowSpan="2"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />

                        <ScrollBar
                                   Grid.Column="1" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   IsTabStop="False"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                   Orientation="Vertical"
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}"
                                   />
                        <ScrollBar 
                                   IsTabStop="False"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                                   Grid.Row="1" 
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}"
                                   />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Who knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please share a [mcve] on Github or OneDrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the style a little and the scrolling worked

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Border x:Name="Root" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        >
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                          Grid.RowSpan="2"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />

                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Orientation="Vertical"
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}"/>

                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It is worth noting that for the Track you need to specify the name x: Name = "PART_Track", so that the custom Thumb would work on pressing

```
<Style x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" 
                           IsDirectionReversed="False" 
                           IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" 
                           Grid.Column="1">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbHorizontal}"
                                   Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I hope this helped not only me)